# Solution of Raman-Nath equation

Tags: optics, acoustics, differential-equations

In this paper [1] the authors claim that the solution of the differential equation

$$
\frac{\partial \varphi_n}{\partial z}+\frac{\nu}{2L}(\varphi_{n-1}-\varphi_{n+1})=-i\frac{nQ}{L}\alpha \varphi_{n}
$$

is

$$
\varphi_n(z)=\exp\left(-i\frac{nQ\alpha z}{2L}\right)J_n\left[\frac{2\nu}{Q\alpha}\sin\left(\frac{Q\alpha z}{2L}\right)\right]
$$

where $J_n$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order $n$. If I calculate the derivate of the above equation what I get is

$$
\frac{\partial \varphi_n}{\partial z}=-i\frac{nQ\alpha}{2L}\varphi_n +\frac{\nu}{L}\cos\left(\frac{Q\alpha z}{2L}\right)\frac{\partial J_n(x)}{\partial x} = \\
=-i\frac{nQ\alpha}{2L}\varphi_n +\frac{\nu}{4L}\exp\left(-i\frac{nQ\alpha z}{2L}\right)\left[\exp\left(i\frac{Q\alpha z}{2L}\right)+\exp\left(-i\frac{Q\alpha z}{2L}\right)\right][J_{n-1}(x)-J_{n+1}(x)] = \\
=-i\frac{nQ\alpha}{2L}\varphi_n +\frac{\nu}{4L}(\varphi_{n-1}-\varphi_{n+1})+\frac{\nu}{4L}\left[\exp\left(-i\frac{(n+1)Q\alpha z}{2L}\right)J_{n-1}(x)-\exp\left(-i\frac{(n-1)Q\alpha z}{2L}\right)J_{n+1}(x)\right]
$$

where I defined

$$
x=\frac{2\nu}{Q\alpha}\sin\left(\frac{Q\alpha z}{2L}\right)
$$

and I used the formula

$$
\frac{\partial J_n(x)}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2}(J_{n-1}(x)-J_{n+1}(x))
$$

Therefore, the solution looks wrong.

What am I missing?

---

[1] R. W. Klein and B. D. Cook, “A Unified Approach to Ultrasonic Light Diffraction,” IEEE Transactions on Sonics and Ultrasonics, Vol. 14, No. 3, 1967, p